# For a charge to have potential, why bring test positive charge closer to the point charge from infinity in uniform speed? why not variable speed?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, potential-energy, voltage

For a charge to have potential, why  bring  test positive charge closer to the point charge from infinity by keeping it in 'electrostatic equilibrium'? or bring the charge closer to the point charge with 'uniform speed'? Why cannot we just bring the charge closer to point charge with variable speeds or acceleration to acquire potential?

Comment: The change in potential will be the same regardless of how the  charge is brought in from infinity

Comment: Or I guess I should say, the change in potential energy will be the same, but this is not directly measurable along any given trajectory. The net work done is what defines the potential energy.

Comment: @tparker Potential depends only on position. In order for the change in potential to equal the work done the change in kinetic energy must be zero

Comment: @BobD Yes I agree (I deleted my incorrect first comment), but what I think the OP is getting at is that the potential energy is often *defined* with respect to paths for which the initial and final speed are the same.

Comment: Conservation of energy then becomes a nontrivial result rather than being true by definition.

Answer (score 6):

The potential difference does not depend on the speed (or, indeed, on the path) of the test charge. It only depends on the initial and final positions of the test charge. So if we set the potential at infinity to be zero (which is conventional) then we can determine the relative potential at any other point by measuring the work done on a test charge as it is brought from infinity to that point in any way whatsoever, as long as its initial and final speeds are the same (so that there is no difference in kinetic energy). There is no need for it to maintain a uniform speed as it travels between the two points.

Comment: Minor nitpick, I would say the “net work” rather than “energy” required. Potential energy is conventionally defined in terms of work in an intro to classical mechanics, so work is arguably the more conceptually  primitive concept (if less directly useful in practice).

Comment: @tparker I believe you would change energy to work, not net work. The net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy.

Comment: @BobD Yep, you’re right. It’s the work that you need to do against the (conservative) force to bring the particle in along any path with the same speed at both (fixed) endpoints. Really not my day today…

Comment: @tparker No problem. We all have them

Comment: @tparker Thank you. I have changed "energy" to "work".

Comment: @gandalf61  I have quoted the first sentence of your answer in my elaboration [Presumptive Physics](https://www.academia.edu/94241181/Presumptive_physics) on page 12.

Answer (score 1):

The potential is a state function that does not depend on the path to reach a specific value, hence it is beneficial to choose the simplest way to calculate the integral. If one performs the calculation in any other way (like constant acceleration or more complex, non-constant acceleration) the solution remains invariant.